# FileReference, send straight to PHP?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, file-upload, flash-builder, filereference

I'd love to be able to send the entire FileReference Object to a PHP Service.

```
uploadTheVideoResult.token = uploadVideo.uploadTheVideo(mFileReference, nameTextInput.text);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Otherwise, what is the best method of sending a File to a PHP Service to be uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can achieve that.  One is to use FileReference (see [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html)) to upload a file to an php page just like how you would do so with regular html upload.  You may check out [swfupload](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/) for some ideas on how to get it implemented.

I recently developed a new way to upload files by using FileReference to read the binaries of files, and the files along with other metadata such as user-input description as Flash remoting to the server-side.  I found that method is actually more straight-forward.  On the server-side, you can use any php solutions that supports Flash remoting such as [AMFPHP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/), [Cabron Connector](http://cabron.sourceforge.net/) or commercial solutions like [WebORB for php](http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-php/).

Comment: I'd love to be able to send the data to a PHP Service. Object to function, and return an Object.